# Windows 7: How to install MySQL Workbench 8.0.25 on a USB flash drive?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I need to install MySQL Workbench 8.0.25 on a Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit.

I've followed this tutorial: https://i12bretro.github.io/tutorials/0540.html with no result.

I guess the Power Shell in Windows 7 is too old because when I try to run the command suggested:
`msiexec /a mysql-workbench-community-8.0.25-winx64.msi /qb TARGETDIR=H:\`

I get a window with the syntax and the options of the command "msiexec" but it is not executed.
Is there anybody who can help me to make it?

Comment: I think you should seriously upgrade to at least windows 10.

Comment: Do you know what is the most recent version can work portable with Windows 7?